# scoring system counting multiple times

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit, swift2

**My Goal: To achieve a scoring system that only counts when a level unit is behind the player once and therefore if the player goes back it doesn’t count the same one twice**

I currently have a scoring system that adds one to the score label every time I tap my player to go forward in my game, this has its flaws as the player can go backwards and then tap to go forward which would count onto the score again if the player went backwards then forwards.

I came up with the idea to count how many platforms(LevelUnits) are behind the player so that if they go back it won’t count the same platform(LevelUnit) twice when they decide to go forward again.

This is what I came up with:

```
override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {      

  let scoreLabel = childNode(withName: "scoreLabel") as! Score // links the scorelabel with Score class

         worldNode.enumerateChildNodes(withName: "levelUnit") {
                node, stop in

        let nodeLocation:CGPoint = self.convert(node.position, from: self.worldNode)   //converts cordinates of level units with the world node.
        let player1Location:CGPoint = self.convert(self.thePlayer.position, from: self.worldNode)

        if (nodeLocation.y < (player1Location.y) - self.levelUnitHeight ) { // checks to see if the node is behind the player's position

               self.countLevelUnits += 1
        }

        if (self.countLevelUnits > scoreLabel.number) {

           while self.countLevelUnits > scoreLabel.number {

               scoreLabel.addOneToScore()

           }

     } else if (self.countLevelUnits < scoreLabel.number) {

         // Do Nothing

    }
  }     
}
```

The only problem is that because they’re constantly behind the player the code counts it multiple times and continues to do so unless I turn off the game. Is there a way to just count the LevelUnits behind the player once for each one that goes behind the players position?

**EDIT 1: LEVEL UNIT CLASS**

```
class LevelUnit:SKNode {

//General Level Unit and Object Variables
var imageName:String = ""
var levelUnitSprite:SKSpriteNode = SKSpriteNode()
var levelUnitWidth:CGFloat = 0 
var levelUnitHeight:CGFloat = 0
var theType:LevelType = LevelType.normal
let thePlayer:Player = Player(imageNamed: "Frog")
var levelUnitPicker = 0
var levelUnitsSpawned = 0

var levelUnitScored:Bool = false

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

override init () {

    super.init()
}


func setUpLevel(){

imageName = “Wall”

    let theSize:CGSize = CGSize(width: levelUnitWidth, height: levelUnitHeight)        //defines the size background sprite as defined by the height and width of level unit
    let tex:SKTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: imageName)                    //defines the testue that the backgroundsprite will have.

    levelUnitSprite = SKSpriteNode(texture: tex, color: SKColor.black, size: theSize)
    scoredLevelUnit = false

    self.addChild(levelUnitSprite)  //adds the level unit to the scene
    self.name = "levelUnit"         //names the whole backgroundsprite under the name level Unit

    self.position = CGPoint(x: levelUnitSprite.size.width / 2, y: 0)


    //The Level Types Physics Body
    if (theType == LevelType.blank) {

        levelUnitSprite.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: levelUnitSprite.size)

        levelUnitSprite.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = BodyType.normal.rawValue
        levelUnitSprite.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = BodyType.normal.rawValue
        levelUnitSprite.physicsBody!.isDynamic = false


    } else if (theType == LevelType.normal) {

        levelUnitSprite.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: levelUnitSprite.size)

        levelUnitSprite.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = BodyType.normal.rawValue
        levelUnitSprite.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = BodyType.normal.rawValue
        levelUnitSprite.physicsBody!.isDynamic = false


    } else if (theType == LevelType.floating) {

        levelUnitSprite.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: levelUnitSprite.size)

        levelUnitSprite.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = BodyType.floating.rawValue
        levelUnitSprite.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = BodyType.floating.rawValue
        levelUnitSprite.physicsBody!.isDynamic = false
    }


}
```

Comment: If you use a custom subclass for your level unit, you can easily add a `Bool` property `scored`; when you "score" this object, set `scored = true`, then next time you can check if `scored == true` and not score it again

Comment: @Paulw11 I added the property but since i'm enumerating through nodes with the same name in the scoring code how do i go about accessing the scored property for each individual levelunit? should I add something like "self.levelUnitScored =  false" in the levelUnit Class and then create an instance of the levelUnit class in the scoring code? I have updated my original post with my level Unit class if you could take a look Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a custom subclass for your level unit, you can easily add a `Bool` property scored; when you "score" this object, set `scored = true`, then next time you can check if `scored == true` and not score it again

```
override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {      

  let scoreLabel = childNode(withName: "scoreLabel") as! Score // links the scorelabel with Score class

  worldNode.enumerateChildNodes(withName: "levelUnit") {
      node, stop in

        if let levelNode = node as? LevelUnit
            let nodeLocation:CGPoint = self.convert(levelNode.position, from: self.worldNode)   //converts cordinates of level units with the world node.
            let player1Location:CGPoint = self.convert(self.thePlayer.position, from: self.worldNode)

             if (nodeLocation.y < (player1Location.y) - self.levelUnitHeight ) { // checks to see if the node is behind the player's position
                 if !levelNode.levelUnitScored {
                     scoreLabel.addOneToScore()
                     levelNode.levelUnitScored = true
                 }
             }
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: It gives me an error on this line "if (levelNode.y < (player1Location.y) " saying that levelNode has no member type 'y' is that supposed to be changed to nodeLocation?

Comment: Yes, sorry.  My mistake